# use region other than us-central1 for Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

From what I can tell, Google Cloud Functions is only available in us-central1, as the drop-down for selecting a region only allows me to select us-central1, and when I try writing my own deploy script using something different for the region option like us-east4, the deploy fails. Is this the case? Is there some hidden way to enable creating a cloud function in us-east4 or some other region?

update: the linked question clarifies this for Firebase but I would love to see an official answer for Cloud Functions in general. My guess based on what I've found online is that until Cloud Functions is out of beta, it will only be available in us-central1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [firebase deploy to custom region (eu-central1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569595/firebase-deploy-to-custom-region-eu-central1)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461164/how-can-i-specify-the-region-of-a-google-cloud-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view the full list of regions available for Cloud Functions, visit this link:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/locations

Current available regions (June, 2020) are:

**Tier 1 pricing**

- `us-central1` (Iowa)
- `us-east1` (South Carolina)
- `us-east4` (Northern Virginia)
- `europe-west1` (Belgium)
- `europe-west2` (London)
- `asia-east2` (Hong Kong)
- `asia-northeast1` (Tokyo)

**Tier 2 pricing**

- `europe-west3` (Frankfurt)
- `europe-west6` (Zurich)
- `us-west3` (Salt Lake City)

Comment: us-east4 (North Virginia) already support Cloud Functions, according to this https://cloud.google.com/about/locations#americas

Comment: as per this link https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/release-notes#June_19_2020 , Sydney (australia-southeast1) is added but when I tried to migrate my cloud functions as functions.region('australia-southeast1').https.onRequest... but I am having an error something like Error: The only valid regions are: us-central1, us-east1... etc.

Answer (score 9):

(Updated July 2018) Good news! Cloud Functions is now available in 4 different regions: Iowa (us-central1), South Carolina (us-east1), Tokyo (asia-northeast1), and Belgium (europe-west1).

To specify your region, you can specify `--region` during deploy, e.g.

`$ gcloud functions deploy howdy --trigger-http --region=europe-west1`

Comment: Hey :) Has this changed since you now officially launched?

Comment: any ETA? still we can only use it in us-central1

Comment: GCF is still in beta, this is why you still have to use `gcloud beta functions deploy`... etc

Comment: For some reason, specifying a function's region is still not possible through the Web UI, even though you can specify any of the four supported regions at the command line; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51881669/2541573.

Comment: As of today it now looks like functions are also available in europe-west1 (Belgium) and asia-east2 (Hong Kong) bringing it to 6 regions globally.