# firebase function with custom domain name in Europe

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am familiar with cloud functions and custom domain names. But this only works for us-central1.
As stated on this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations) for more information

> Important: If you are using HTTP functions to serve dynamic content
>   for Firebase Hosting, you must use us-central1.

Firebase evolved over time, 3 years ago everything was in us-central, now it's possible to run Firestore and Cloud Functions in Europe.

But sadly the custom domain name for cloud functions is only supported for us-central1. Does anybody know how to get this done for other regions?

Is there such support in the Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53528902/2541573

Comment: The documentation for Firebase Hosting is correct - It's still not supported outside of us-central1.

Answer (score 0):

It's now possible to host your cloud function (v1) that is connected to a domain in different location. Here is my config to host our api in europe

```
    "hosting": [
        {
            "target": "api",
            "rewrites": [
                {
                    "source": "**",
                    "function": "api",
                    "region": "europe-west1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```